# How to solve WPF Popup Notify in taskbar to rightbottom of the screen in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, notifyicon

I stuck on WPF popup notifyicon in taskbar,it does not show the popup notification on the screen.
Am tried the below code in c#

```
 public void report()
 {
  //Here am selected the value from database and stored it in "str" ,upto 
       //this working fine
  string title = "Report Received";
  string str = value from database

  NotifyIcon nic = new NotifyIcon();
  nic.Text = str;                  
  nic.BalloonTipText = str;
  nic.BalloonTipTitle = title;
  nic.Visible = true;
  nic.ShowBalloonTip(1000, title, text, ToolTipIcon.Info);
}
```

how to work this perfectly,am stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an icon before call ShowBalloonTip to get this working:

```
nic.Icon = new Icon(@"PATH/TO/AN/ICON.ico");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How to give this as popup?

Comment: ShowBalloonTip() should show the popup. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: :Yes,i mean it like a rectangle box in Popup obj=new Popup()please helpme

Comment: You could use a third party tool: For example [Tulpep](https://github.com/Tulpep/Notification-Popup-Window). Or another good customizable [example](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/aacbc77c-4ef6-456f-80b7-1f157c2909f7/)